# code splitting vuex application

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuex

I have a [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex) store and i'd like to apply code splitting on it.

Following [this tutorial](https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/07/16/Lazy-load-in-Vue-using-Webpack-s-code-splitting/) I tried this:

```
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import Vue from 'vue'
import createLogger from 'vuex/dist/logger'

Vue.use(Vuex)
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: debug,
  plugins: debug ? [createLogger] : [],
  state: {
    loading: false
  },
  mutations: {
    toggleLoading: (state) => {
      state.loading = !state.loading
    }
  },
  getters: {
    loading: state => state.loading
  },
  actions: {
    toggleLoading: ({commit}) => {
      commit('toggleLoading')
    }
  }
})

import('./modules/userModule').then(userModule => {
  store.registerModule('user', userModule)
})
import('./modules/tenantsModule').then(tenantsModule => {
  store.registerModule('tenants', tenantsModule)
})
import('./modules/updatesModule').then(updatesModule => {
  store.registerModule('updates', updatesModule)
})

export default store
```

But the application fails :

> webpack-internal:///24:739 [vuex] unknown getter: user

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: That error would appear if you were trying to access the `user` getter, which you haven't defined. Either by `this.$store.getters.user` or `mapGetters(['user'])`. Do you access a getter like that anywhere else in your code?

Comment: @thanksd - I did define it, and it works if i don't use code splitting. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that it now loads the modules  async.

Comment: Ahhh ok, you're defining it in your `user` module. I understand now. Yes, it's definitely because that module hasn't been loaded at the time you're trying to access it. Not sure what the solution is though...

Answer (score 1):

If are using `export default` in your modules you need to access it through dot notation (something I read [here](http://2ality.com/2017/01/import-operator.html) under 4.2). So something like the below worked for me:

```
import('./modules/userModule').then(userModule => {
    store.registerModule('user', userModule.default)
})
```

However, I had some issues with this approach. I often use the store on an initial page load and by then the module hasn't been loaded yet. So I register the part of the store that I need initially directly when declaring the store, like so:

```
import userModule from './modules/userModule'

Vue.use(Vuex);

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {userModule}
})
```

Hope this helps!